# ReactJS - Update value via Button

Tags: reactjs

I just started with ReactJS. Running into basic issues, Basically I want to create a button which changes the list values.

```
function Butt(e) {
  const [x, back] = useState(0);

  return (
      <>
      <ui>
        <Li a="One" b="Two"/>
        <Li a="Three" b="Four" onClick="up"/>
        <Li a="Five" b="Six"/>
        <Li a="Seven" b ="Eight"/>
        </ui>
        <button onClick = {(event)=>alert(event)}> Click me </button>
      </>
  );
}

function Li({a, b}) {
  return (
      <>
          <p>This is a paragraph.. </p>
          <ul>
              <li>{a}</li>
              <li>{b}</li>
          </ul>
      </>
  );
}

createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
    <>
     <Butt/>
     </>
);
```

So I created a button like this:

```
   <button onClick = {(event)=>alert(event)}> Click me </button>
```

But not sure how to refer the values of a, b and change them, or append them like 'One is a number'.

Comment: In this case, x is the value and back is the function to update x. to update x on button click use ```onClick={() => back(34)}```

Answer (score 0):

For this, you must keep all the data in the state.

```
const { useState } = require("react");

const initItems = [
    { a: "One", b: "Two" }, 
    { a: "Three", b: "Four"}, 
    { a: "Five", b: "Six"}, 
    { a: "Seven", b: "Eight"}, 
    { a: "Nine", b: "Ten"}
]

const data = [items, setItem] = useState(initItems);
```

You should use the setItem method to change the data in the state

```
setItem([...items, { a: "Nine", b: "Ten" }])
```

use this to list

```
items.map((item, index) => {
    return (
        <div key={index}>
            <p>{item.a}</p>
            <p>{item.b}</p>
        </div>
    )
})
```